# How to change tab icon in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, freemarker, netbeans-7

Is it possible to change that ugly red dot icon on NetBeans tab with `index.ftl`? It comes with [`Freemarker plugin`](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/52115/freemarker-netbeans-plugin) and indicates a ftl template.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the tab icon of this plugin you can follow the steps bellow:

1. Go to the Netbeans modules directory. In Linux it is `cd $HOME/.netbeans/7.4/module` where `$HOME` is your home directory. You can check where is this directory in different OSs in [`Netbeans Wiki`](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir).
2. There, you will find a file named `org-ftl.jar`. Inside this file go to `org/ftl` and you will see your icon which is named `dot.png`.
3. Substitute `dot.png` file by your desired icon and open Netbeans. Your will see your new icon in your Freemarker tabs.

Answer (score 0):

It is not configurable, but with a little hacking, I think you can do this. There must be a png somewhere in a jar of the freemarker plugin or in one of the core files of netbeans. You would need to unzip the jar, update the picture and then zip it back (to jar).

[Here's the plugin sources](https://github.com/rostanek/freemarker-support-for-netbeans) and [Here's the icon](https://github.com/rostanek/freemarker-support-for-netbeans/blob/master/src/org/netbeans/freemarker/icon.png). It doesn't look like the one you showed. Maybe you're using some other plugin?

Comment: well, the plugin was installed with menu: service -> modules so installation was provided by netbeans

Comment: seems  the other version was downloaded, look at this https://github.com/nbphpcouncil/freemarker_NB_highlighting/blob/master/src/org/ftl/dot.png